# Opening Flutter screen in new Tab on web

Tags: flutter, navigation, github-issues

I want to open a flutter screen on new tab on a button click. I am using this code.

`html.window.open('/#/external_screen',"_blank");`

Where external_screen is route of my screen I want to open in new Tab. Using this code it opens that screen but immediately navigates back to previous screen in new Tab.
Can anyone Help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

`html.window.open('/#/external_screen',"_blank");`

Open Screen in new Tab in flutter web

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing this using dart:js

Import dart:js:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
```

Use this method to open the page in new tab

```
js.context.callMethod('open', ['https://yourwebsite.com/']);
```